# Add description line to jQuery colorbox application

Tags: colorbox

I can't add a description lines to images in colorbox 1.3.9. I'm using the following code:

```
(function($) {      
 $(document).ready(function(){   
$ (".colorbox").colorbox({  opacity:"0.8",width:"80%",height:"90%",current: "image : {current} / {total}" 
});
});

 })(jQuery);
```

Is there any way to add description line to colorbox?

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do and is spelled out in the ColorBox docs.

Use the TITLE attribute to store a short description of the photo or other digital asset as follows:

```
<a class="group1 cboxElement" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a>
```

Each asset may have its own description.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you for your reply. But, you misunderstood me. I want to add description line rather than title. I know to add title and want to add both title and description. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. AFAIK, this feature isn't offered by the plug-in directly (although I've seen it asked about before).  You'd have to get into the javascript a bit and add the feature, which maybe isn't possible for you. A different approach would be to use ColorBox to open HTML pages (instead of images) that contained both the image and the description.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert HTML in the `title` attribute:

```
<a class="cboxElement" rel="group1" href="path/to/image" title="<h1>Title</h1><p>Description</p>">Grouped Photo 1</a>
```

You should be able to style the output with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes to read Description from alt attribute of link.

Example

```
<a href="test.jpg" alt="test description in alt tag" title="test title" class="groupGallery">
```

Javacript

I have added lines in js file

```
/*!
Colorbox v1.5.9 - 2014-04-25
jQuery lightbox and modal window plugin
(c) 2014 Jack Moore - http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox
license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/
(function ($, document, window) {
.
.
.
    rel: function () {
        return this.rel;
    },
    href: function () {
        // using this.href would give the absolute url, when the href may have been inteded as a selector (e.g. '#container')
        return $(this).attr('href');
    },
    title: function () {
        return this.title;
    },
    description: function () {  //code to add description at bottom
        return $(this).attr('alt');;
    }
},


// Abstracting the HTML and event identifiers for easy rebranding
colorbox = 'colorbox',
prefix = 'cbox',
boxElement = prefix + 'Element',

// Events
event_open = prefix + '_open',
event_load = prefix + '_load',
event_complete = prefix + '_complete',
event_cleanup = prefix + '_cleanup',
event_closed = prefix + '_closed',
event_purge = prefix + '_purge',

// Cached jQuery Object Variables
$overlay,
$box,
$wrap,
$content,
$topBorder,
$leftBorder,
$rightBorder,
$bottomBorder,
$related,
$window,
$loaded,
$loadingBay,
$loadingOverlay,
$title,
$current,
$description, //code to add description at bottom
$slideshow,
$next,
$prev,
$close,
$groupControls,
$events = $('<a/>'), // $({}) would be prefered, but there is an issue with jQuery 1.4.2

.
.
.

function launch(element) {
    var options;

    if (!closing) {

        options = $(element).data('colorbox');

        settings = new Settings(element, options);

        getRelated(settings.get('rel'));

        if (!open) {
            open = active = true; // Prevents the page-change action from queuing up if the visitor holds down the left or right keys.

            setClass(settings.get('className'));

            // Show colorbox so the sizes can be calculated in older versions of jQuery
            $box.css({ visibility: 'hidden', display: 'block', opacity: '' });

            $loaded = $tag(div, 'LoadedContent', 'width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden');
            $content.css({ width: '', height: '' }).append($loaded);

            // Cache values needed for size calculations
            interfaceHeight = $topBorder.height() + $bottomBorder.height() + $content.outerHeight(true) - $content.height() + 25; //code to add description at bottom and increase height of light box
            interfaceWidth = $leftBorder.width() + $rightBorder.width() + $content.outerWidth(true) - $content.width() ;
            loadedHeight = $loaded.outerHeight(true);
            loadedWidth = $loaded.outerWidth(true);

            // Opens inital empty Colorbox prior to content being loaded.
            var initialWidth = setSize(settings.get('initialWidth'), 'x');
            var initialHeight = setSize(settings.get('initialHeight'), 'y');
            var maxWidth = settings.get('maxWidth');
            var maxHeight = settings.get('maxHeight');

            settings.w = (maxWidth !== false ? Math.min(initialWidth, setSize(maxWidth, 'x')) : initialWidth) - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
            settings.h = (maxHeight !== false ? Math.min(initialHeight, setSize(maxHeight, 'y')) : initialHeight) - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;

            $loaded.css({ width: '', height: settings.h });
            publicMethod.position();

            trigger(event_open);
            settings.get('onOpen');

            $groupControls.add($title).hide();
            $groupControls.add($description).hide();  //code to add description at bottom

            $box.focus();

            if (settings.get('trapFocus')) {
                // Confine focus to the modal
                // Uses event capturing that is not supported in IE8-
                if (document.addEventListener) {

                    document.addEventListener('focus', trapFocus, true);

                    $events.one(event_closed, function () {
                        document.removeEventListener('focus', trapFocus, true);
                    });
                }
            }

            // Return focus on closing
            if (settings.get('returnFocus')) {
                $events.one(event_closed, function () {
                    $(settings.el).focus();
                });
            }
        }

        $overlay.css({
            opacity: parseFloat(settings.get('opacity')) || '',
            cursor: settings.get('overlayClose') ? 'pointer' : '',
            visibility: 'visible'
        }).show();

        if (settings.get('closeButton')) {
            $close.html(settings.get('close')).appendTo($content);
        } else {
            $close.appendTo('<div/>'); // replace with .detach() when dropping jQuery < 1.4
        }

        load();
    }
}

// Colorbox's markup needs to be added to the DOM prior to being called
// so that the browser will go ahead and load the CSS background images.
function appendHTML() {
    if (!$box && document.body) {
        init = false;
        $window = $(window);
        $box = $tag(div).attr({
            id: colorbox,
            'class': $.support.opacity === false ? prefix + 'IE' : '', // class for optional IE8 & lower targeted CSS.
            role: 'dialog',
            tabindex: '-1'
        }).hide();
        $overlay = $tag(div, "Overlay").hide();
        $loadingOverlay = $([$tag(div, "LoadingOverlay")[0], $tag(div, "LoadingGraphic")[0]]);
        $wrap = $tag(div, "Wrapper");
        $content = $tag(div, "Content").append(
            $title = $tag(div, "Title"),
            $current = $tag(div, "Current"),
            $description = $tag(div, "Description"), //code to add description at bottom
            $prev = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({ id: prefix + 'Previous' }),
            $next = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({ id: prefix + 'Next' }),
            $slideshow = $tag('button', "Slideshow"),
            $loadingOverlay
        );

        $close = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({ id: prefix + 'Close' });

        $wrap.append( // The 3x3 Grid that makes up Colorbox
            $tag(div).append(
                $tag(div, "TopLeft"),
                $topBorder = $tag(div, "TopCenter"),
                $tag(div, "TopRight")
            ),
            $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                $leftBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleLeft"),
                $content,
                $rightBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleRight")
            ),
            $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                $tag(div, "BottomLeft"),
                $bottomBorder = $tag(div, "BottomCenter"),
                $tag(div, "BottomRight")
            )
        ).find('div div').css({ 'float': 'left' });

        $loadingBay = $tag(div, false, 'position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none; max-width:none;');

        $groupControls = $next.add($prev).add($current).add($slideshow);

        $(document.body).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
    }
}

// Add Colorbox's event bindings
function addBindings() {
    function clickHandler(e) {
        // ignore non-left-mouse-clicks and clicks modified with ctrl / command, shift, or alt.
        // See: http://jacklmoore.com/notes/click-events/
        if (!(e.which > 1 || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            launch(this);
        }
    }

    if ($box) {
        if (!init) {
            init = true;

            // Anonymous functions here keep the public method from being cached, thereby allowing them to be redefined on the fly.
            $next.click(function () {
                publicMethod.next();
            });
            $prev.click(function () {
                publicMethod.prev();
            });
            $close.click(function () {
                publicMethod.close();
            });
            $overlay.click(function () {
                if (settings.get('overlayClose')) {
                    publicMethod.close();
                }
            });

            // Key Bindings
            $(document).bind('keydown.' + prefix, function (e) {
                var key = e.keyCode;
                if (open && settings.get('escKey') && key === 27) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    publicMethod.close();
                }
                if (open && settings.get('arrowKey') && $related[1] && !e.altKey) {
                    if (key === 37) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $prev.click();
                    } else if (key === 39) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $next.click();
                    }
                }
            });

            if ($.isFunction($.fn.on)) {
                // For jQuery 1.7+
                $(document).on('click.' + prefix, '.' + boxElement, clickHandler);
            } else {
                // For jQuery 1.3.x -> 1.6.x
                // This code is never reached in jQuery 1.9, so do not contact me about 'live' being removed.
                // This is not here for jQuery 1.9, it's here for legacy users.
                $('.' + boxElement).live('click.' + prefix, clickHandler);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Don't do anything if Colorbox already exists.
if ($.colorbox) {
    return;
}

// Append the HTML when the DOM loads
$(appendHTML);


// ****************
// PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
// Usage format: $.colorbox.close();
// Usage from within an iframe: parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
// ****************

publicMethod = $.fn[colorbox] = $[colorbox] = function (options, callback) {
    var settings;
    var $obj = this;

    options = options || {};

    if ($.isFunction($obj)) { // assume a call to $.colorbox
        $obj = $('<a/>');
        options.open = true;
    } else if (!$obj[0]) { // colorbox being applied to empty collection
        return $obj;
    }


    if (!$obj[0]) { // colorbox being applied to empty collection
        return $obj;
    }

    appendHTML();

    if (addBindings()) {

        if (callback) {
            options.onComplete = callback;
        }

        $obj.each(function () {
            var old = $.data(this, colorbox) || {};
            $.data(this, colorbox, $.extend(old, options));
        }).addClass(boxElement);

        settings = new Settings($obj[0], options);

        if (settings.get('open')) {
            launch($obj[0]);
        }
    }

    return $obj;
};

publicMethod.position = function (speed, loadedCallback) {
    var
    css,
    top = 0,
    left = 0,
    offset = $box.offset(),
    scrollTop,
    scrollLeft;

    $window.unbind('resize.' + prefix);

    // remove the modal so that it doesn't influence the document width/height
    $box.css({ top: -9e4, left: -9e4 });

    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft();

    if (settings.get('fixed')) {
        offset.top -= scrollTop;
        offset.left -= scrollLeft;
        $box.css({ position: 'fixed' });
    } else {
        top = scrollTop;
        left = scrollLeft;
        $box.css({ position: 'absolute' });
    }

    // keeps the top and left positions within the browser's viewport.
    if (settings.get('right') !== false) {
        left += Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth - setSize(settings.get('right'), 'x'), 0);
    } else if (settings.get('left') !== false) {
        left += setSize(settings.get('left'), 'x');
    } else {
        left += Math.round(Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth, 0) / 2);
    }

    if (settings.get('bottom') !== false) {
        top += Math.max(winheight() - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight - setSize(settings.get('bottom'), 'y'), 0);
    } else if (settings.get('top') !== false) {
        top += setSize(settings.get('top'), 'y');
    } else {
        top += Math.round(Math.max(winheight() - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight, 0) / 2);
    }

    $box.css({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left, visibility: 'visible' });

    // this gives the wrapper plenty of breathing room so it's floated contents can move around smoothly,
    // but it has to be shrank down around the size of div#colorbox when it's done.  If not,
    // it can invoke an obscure IE bug when using iframes.
    $wrap[0].style.width = $wrap[0].style.height = "9999px";

    function modalDimensions() {
        $topBorder[0].style.width = $bottomBorder[0].style.width = $content[0].style.width = (parseInt($box[0].style.width, 10) - interfaceWidth) + 'px';
        $content[0].style.height = $leftBorder[0].style.height = $rightBorder[0].style.height = (parseInt($box[0].style.height, 10) - interfaceHeight) + 'px';
    }

    css = { width: settings.w + loadedWidth + interfaceWidth, height: settings.h + loadedHeight + interfaceHeight, top: top, left: left };

    // setting the speed to 0 if the content hasn't changed size or position
    if (speed) {
        var tempSpeed = 0;
        $.each(css, function (i) {
            if (css[i] !== previousCSS[i]) {
                tempSpeed = speed;
                return;
            }
        });
        speed = tempSpeed;
    }

    previousCSS = css;

    if (!speed) {
        $box.css(css);
    }

    $box.dequeue().animate(css, {
        duration: speed || 0,
        complete: function () {
            modalDimensions();

            active = false;

            // shrink the wrapper down to exactly the size of colorbox to avoid a bug in IE's iframe implementation.
            $wrap[0].style.width = (settings.w + loadedWidth + interfaceWidth) + "px";
            $wrap[0].style.height = (settings.h + loadedHeight + interfaceHeight) + "px";

            if (settings.get('reposition')) {
                setTimeout(function () {  // small delay before binding onresize due to an IE8 bug.
                    $window.bind('resize.' + prefix, publicMethod.position);
                }, 1);
            }

            if (loadedCallback) {
                loadedCallback();
            }
        },
        step: modalDimensions
    });
};

publicMethod.resize = function (options) {
    var scrolltop;

    if (open) {
        options = options || {};

        if (options.width) {
            settings.w = setSize(options.width, 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
        }

        if (options.innerWidth) {
            settings.w = setSize(options.innerWidth, 'x');
        }

        $loaded.css({ width: settings.w });

        if (options.height) {
            settings.h = setSize(options.height, 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;
        }

        if (options.innerHeight) {
            settings.h = setSize(options.innerHeight, 'y');
        }

        if (!options.innerHeight && !options.height) {
            scrolltop = $loaded.scrollTop();
            $loaded.css({ height: "auto" });
            settings.h = $loaded.height();
        }

        $loaded.css({ height: settings.h });

        if (scrolltop) {
            $loaded.scrollTop(scrolltop);
        }

        publicMethod.position(settings.get('transition') === "none" ? 0 : settings.get('speed'));
    }
};

publicMethod.prep = function (object) {
    if (!open) {
        return;
    }

    var callback, speed = settings.get('transition') === "none" ? 0 : settings.get('speed');

    $loaded.remove();

    $loaded = $tag(div, 'LoadedContent').append(object);

    function getWidth() {
        settings.w = settings.w || $loaded.width();
        settings.w = settings.mw && settings.mw < settings.w ? settings.mw : settings.w;
        return settings.w;
    }
    function getHeight() {
        settings.h = settings.h || $loaded.height();
        settings.h = settings.mh && settings.mh < settings.h ? settings.mh : settings.h;
        return settings.h;
    }

    $loaded.hide()
    .appendTo($loadingBay.show())// content has to be appended to the DOM for accurate size calculations.
    .css({ width: getWidth(), overflow: settings.get('scrolling') ? 'auto' : 'hidden' })
    .css({ height: getHeight() })// sets the height independently from the width in case the new width influences the value of height.
    .prependTo($content);

    $loadingBay.hide();

    // floating the IMG removes the bottom line-height and fixed a problem where IE miscalculates the width of the parent element as 100% of the document width.

    $(photo).css({ 'float': 'none' });

    setClass(settings.get('className'));

    callback = function () {
        var total = $related.length,
            iframe,
            complete;

        if (!open) {
            return;
        }

        function removeFilter() { // Needed for IE8 in versions of jQuery prior to 1.7.2
            if ($.support.opacity === false) {
                $box[0].style.removeAttribute('filter');
            }
        }

        complete = function () {
            clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
            $loadingOverlay.hide();
            trigger(event_complete);
            settings.get('onComplete');
        };


        $title.html(settings.get('title')).show();
        $description.html(settings.get('description')).show(); //code to add description at bottom
        $loaded.show();

        if (total > 1) { // handle grouping
            if (typeof settings.get('current') === "string") {
                $current.html(settings.get('current').replace('{current}', index + 1).replace('{total}', total)).show();
            }

            $next[(settings.get('loop') || index < total - 1) ? "show" : "hide"]().html(settings.get('next'));
            $prev[(settings.get('loop') || index) ? "show" : "hide"]().html(settings.get('previous'));

            slideshow();

            // Preloads images within a rel group
            if (settings.get('preloading')) {
                $.each([getIndex(-1), getIndex(1)], function () {
                    var img,
                        i = $related[this],
                        settings = new Settings(i, $.data(i, colorbox)),
                        src = settings.get('href');

                    if (src && isImage(settings, src)) {
                        src = retinaUrl(settings, src);
                        img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.src = src;
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            $groupControls.hide();
        }

        if (settings.get('iframe')) {
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

            if ('frameBorder' in iframe) {
                iframe.frameBorder = 0;
            }

            if ('allowTransparency' in iframe) {
                iframe.allowTransparency = "true";
            }

            if (!settings.get('scrolling')) {
                iframe.scrolling = "no";
            }

            $(iframe)
                .attr({
                    src: settings.get('href'),
                    name: (new Date()).getTime(), // give the iframe a unique name to prevent caching
                    'class': prefix + 'Iframe',
                    allowFullScreen: true // allow HTML5 video to go fullscreen
                })
                .one('load', complete)
                .appendTo($loaded);

            $events.one(event_purge, function () {
                iframe.src = "//about:blank";
            });

            if (settings.get('fastIframe')) {
                $(iframe).trigger('load');
            }
        } else {
            complete();
        }

        if (settings.get('transition') === 'fade') {
            $box.fadeTo(speed, 1, removeFilter);
        } else {
            removeFilter();
        }
    };

    if (settings.get('transition') === 'fade') {
        $box.fadeTo(speed, 0, function () {
            publicMethod.position(0, callback);
        });
    } else {
        publicMethod.position(speed, callback);
    }
};

function load() {
    var href, setResize, prep = publicMethod.prep, $inline, request = ++requests;

    active = true;

    photo = false;

    trigger(event_purge);
    trigger(event_load);
    settings.get('onLoad');

    settings.h = settings.get('height') ?
            setSize(settings.get('height'), 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight  :
            settings.get('innerHeight') && setSize(settings.get('innerHeight'), 'y') ;

    settings.w = settings.get('width') ?
            setSize(settings.get('width'), 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth :
            settings.get('innerWidth') && setSize(settings.get('innerWidth'), 'x');

    // Sets the minimum dimensions for use in image scaling
    settings.mw = settings.w;
    settings.mh = settings.h;

    // Re-evaluate the minimum width and height based on maxWidth and maxHeight values.
    // If the width or height exceed the maxWidth or maxHeight, use the maximum values instead.
    if (settings.get('maxWidth')) {
        settings.mw = setSize(settings.get('maxWidth'), 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
        settings.mw = settings.w && settings.w < settings.mw ? settings.w : settings.mw;
    }
    if (settings.get('maxHeight')) {
        settings.mh = setSize(settings.get('maxHeight'), 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;
        settings.mh = settings.h && settings.h < settings.mh ? settings.h : settings.mh;
    }

    href = settings.get('href');

    loadingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $loadingOverlay.show();
    }, 100);

    if (settings.get('inline')) {
        var $target = $(href);
        // Inserts an empty placeholder where inline content is being pulled from.
        // An event is bound to put inline content back when Colorbox closes or loads new content.
        $inline = $('<div>').hide().insertBefore($target);

        $events.one(event_purge, function () {
            $inline.replaceWith($target);
        });

        prep($target);
    } else if (settings.get('iframe')) {
        // IFrame element won't be added to the DOM until it is ready to be displayed,
        // to avoid problems with DOM-ready JS that might be trying to run in that iframe.
        prep(" ");
    } else if (settings.get('html')) {
        prep(settings.get('html'));
    } else if (isImage(settings, href)) {

        href = retinaUrl(settings, href);

        photo = new Image();

        $(photo)
        .addClass(prefix + 'Photo')
        .bind('error', function () {
            prep($tag(div, 'Error').html(settings.get('imgError')));
        })
        .one('load', function () {
            if (request !== requests) {
                return;
            }

            // A small pause because some browsers will occassionaly report a 
            // img.width and img.height of zero immediately after the img.onload fires
            setTimeout(function () {
                var percent;

                $.each(['alt', 'longdesc', 'aria-describedby'], function (i, val) {
                    var attr = $(settings.el).attr(val) || $(settings.el).attr('data-' + val);
                    if (attr) {
                        photo.setAttribute(val, attr);
                    }
                });

                if (settings.get('retinaImage') && window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
                    photo.height = photo.height / window.devicePixelRatio;
                    photo.width = photo.width / window.devicePixelRatio;
                }

                if (settings.get('scalePhotos')) {
                    setResize = function () {
                        photo.height -= photo.height * percent;
                        photo.width -= photo.width * percent;
                    };
                    if (settings.mw && photo.width > settings.mw) {
                        percent = (photo.width - settings.mw) / photo.width;
                        setResize();
                    }
                    if (settings.mh && photo.height > settings.mh) {
                        percent = (photo.height - settings.mh) / photo.height;
                        setResize();
                    }
                }

                if (settings.h) {
                    photo.style.marginTop = Math.max(settings.mh - photo.height, 0) / 2 + 'px';
                }

                if ($related[1] && (settings.get('loop') || $related[index + 1])) {
                    photo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    photo.onclick = function () {
                        publicMethod.next();
                    };
                }

                photo.style.width = photo.width + 'px';
                photo.style.height = photo.height + 'px';
                prep(photo);
            }, 1);
        });

        photo.src = href;

    } else if (href) {
        $loadingBay.load(href, settings.get('data'), function (data, status) {
            if (request === requests) {
                prep(status === 'error' ? $tag(div, 'Error').html(settings.get('xhrError')) : $(this).contents());
            }
        });
    }
}

// Navigates to the next page/image in a set.
publicMethod.next = function () {
    if (!active && $related[1] && (settings.get('loop') || $related[index + 1])) {
        index = getIndex(1);
        launch($related[index]);
    }
};

publicMethod.prev = function () {
    if (!active && $related[1] && (settings.get('loop') || index)) {
        index = getIndex(-1);
        launch($related[index]);
    }
};

// Note: to use this within an iframe use the following format: parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
publicMethod.close = function () {
    if (open && !closing) {

        closing = true;
        open = false;
        trigger(event_cleanup);
        settings.get('onCleanup');
        $window.unbind('.' + prefix);
        $overlay.fadeTo(settings.get('fadeOut') || 0, 0);

        $box.stop().fadeTo(settings.get('fadeOut') || 0, 0, function () {
            $box.hide();
            $overlay.hide();
            trigger(event_purge);
            $loaded.remove();

            setTimeout(function () {
                closing = false;
                trigger(event_closed);
                settings.get('onClosed');
            }, 1);
        });
    }
};

// Removes changes Colorbox made to the document, but does not remove the plugin.
publicMethod.remove = function () {
    if (!$box) { return; }

    $box.stop();
    $.colorbox.close();
    $box.stop().remove();
    $overlay.remove();
    closing = false;
    $box = null;
    $('.' + boxElement)
        .removeData(colorbox)
        .removeClass(boxElement);

    $(document).unbind('click.' + prefix);
};

// A method for fetching the current element Colorbox is referencing.
// returns a jQuery object.
publicMethod.element = function () {
    return $(settings.el);
};

publicMethod.settings = defaults;

}(jQuery, document, window));
```

CSS
added following line below #cboxCurrent element

```
#cboxDescription{position:relative; top:-5px;left:0; color:#ccc; font-size:16px; padding:3px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread - but I came across this recently and solved it by just using the pagination element instead (assuming you don't need that as well!):

```
    $('.gallery a').colorbox({rel:'gal', current:function () {
    var description = $(this).attr('alt');
    if (description == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return ""+description+"";
    }
    }});
```

I placed the description in the span as it was overlaying the image, and if it wasn't present I didn't want the semi-transparent background to be seen - the description also comes from the alt element of the link, which accessibility-wise is a bit of a win as well!

Hope this helps!